# Q: How to change cluster_cookie in bootstrapped Tarantool Cartridge cluster?

Tags: tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

Is there any way to change `cluster_cookie` in already bootstrapped cluster?
Should I just set new `cartridge.cfg.cluster_cookie` and reboot Tarantool instances or some additional actions are required?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a new cookie and restarting every instance is enough. You can set it either in `cartridge.cfg()` options, or in `instance.yml` config. Don't forget to update it everywhere, or the Cartridge will complain that a member is non-decryptable.